# org.apache.cordova.api doesn't exist. PhoneGap 3.0

Tags: android, cordova

I'm trying to add VideoPlayer plugin (https://github.com/macdonst/VideoPlayer) to my phonegap Android app.

While compiling I get problem:

```
VideoPlayer.java:25: error: package org.apache.cordova.api does not exist"
```

Line 25:

```
import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
```

Comment: Solved. Replace 'import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;' -> 'import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;'

Answer (score 18):

change your import to:

```
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
```

Answer (score 9):

I ran in to this same issue while using StatusBarNotification plugin with Cordova 3.0.
I had to do similar modifications in StatusBarNotification.java.
Commented lines are the original lines and uncommented lines to replace them.
Hope this will be useful to other programmers out there who run in to this same issue.

```
//import org.apache.cordova.api.CallbackContext;
import org.apache.cordova.CallbackContext;
//import org.apache.cordova.api.CordovaPlugin;
import org.apache.cordova.CordovaPlugin;
```